# Read serialized array of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I saved a file with a serialized `String` array that contains 3 arrays (1 `String` and 2 `Double`).

How can i read it back and redo the 3 arrays?

Here's how I write it :

```
String[] storeAllArrays[] = {prod, cant, pret};

    ObjectOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.ser"));
        out.writeObject(storeAllArrays);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

EDIT : Here's what i tried :

```
 try {
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.ser"));
    String[] arrayT = (String[]) in.readObject();
        in.close();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ArrayT);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: 1) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Almost the same but with `ObjectInputStream` instead of `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: It should be `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, arrayT);`

Comment: And the problem with this code is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example of serializing and deserializing

```
    String[] prod = { "pr", "od" };
    String[] cant = { "10.0", "20.0" };
    String[] pret = { "30.0", "40.0" };
    String[] storeAllArrays[] = {prod, cant, pret};

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SerializerSample.class.getName());
    String serializedPath = "/tmp/store_test.ser";

    ObjectOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serializedPath));
        out.writeObject(storeAllArrays);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try {
        InputStream file = new FileInputStream(serializedPath);
        InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
        ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);

        String[] storeAllArraysREAD[] = (String[][]) input.readObject();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, storeAllArraysREAD.toString());

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform input. Class not found.",
                ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform input.", ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write the String and two doubles, as a String and two doubles.

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.data"));
dos.writeUTF(prod);
dos.writeDouble(cant);
dos.writeDouble(pret);
dos.close();
```

to read

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.data"));
prod = dis.readUTF();
cant = dis.readDouble();
pret = dis.readDouble();
dis.close();
```

if you must use ObjectOutputStream you can use ObjectInputStream

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.data"));
String[] array = (String[]) dis.readObject();
dis.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of `ObjectInputStream`? It's for reading files created with `ObjectOutputStream`. You construct one like this:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.ser"));
```

Then you can read your arrays in like this:

```
Object[] array = (Object[]) ois.readObject();
```